# Magento: "Cannot reindex."

Tags: magento, indexing, reporting

My "Category Products" index is having problems. It simply won't reindex. I was on 1.4 when the error started, now I'm on 1.5 and it's still there.

I have tried:

1. Repairing the database with the magento database repair tool
2. Clearing var, all cache, locks, sessions
3. Making sure all permissions are right.
4. Ripping my hair out.

Is there anyway I can investigate this issue further? Error logs don't make note of this problem, and I'm somewhat in the dark. Any help would be very, very appreciated.

Edit: After echoing out the error message I get: Report! SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.

Edit 2: I've run a query log and have the following info. If you don't mind taking a look and seeing if a solution springs to mind I'd be very happy. It's slightly over my head...

```
[2011-06-14 12:33:26] SQL: SELECT DISTINCT `catalog_product_bundle_selection`.`parent_product_id` FROM `catalog_product_bundle_selection` WHERE (product_id IN('180'))
EXCEPTION 
exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1' in /my-domain.com/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /my-domain.com/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /my-domain.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(468): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#2 /my-domain.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO cat...', Array)
#3 /my-domain.com/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(335): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO cat...', Array)
#4 /my-domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php(159): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO cat...')
#5 /my-domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Category/Indexer/Product.php(522): Mage_Index_Model_Mysql4_Abstract->insertFromSelect('SELECT?        ...', 'catalog_categor...', Array)
#6 /my-domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(125): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Indexer_Product->reindexAll()
#7 /my-domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(139): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#8 /my-domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(167): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#9 /my-domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(124): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#10 /my-domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()
#11 /my-domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')
#12 /my-domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(177): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /my-domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(304): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /my-domain.com/app/Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /my-domain.com/index.php(81): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

Edit 3: The Query itself!

SQL:

```sql
INSERT INTO catalog_category_anc_products_index_idx 
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN DISTINCT ca.category_id, cp.product_id
FROM catalog_category_anc_categs_index_idx AS ca
    INNER JOIN catalog_category_entity AS ce
        ON ce.path LIKE ca.path OR ce.entity_id = ca.category_id
    INNER JOIN catalog_category_product AS cp
        ON cp.category_id = ce.entity_id
    INNER JOIN catalog_category_product_index_enbl_idx as pv
        ON pv.product_id = cp.product_id
```

Answer (score 4):

This error -always- indicates that an exception was thrown somewhere in the index process.

To verify, check method 'reindexProcessAction' in the following file:

app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php

Please echo and die $e->getMessage() in the second catch block and report back ;)

edit1:

In regards to your exception, according to google, this -may- be due to PHP locale-specific floatval formatting... try to put:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_EN');
```

at the top of your index.php file. Others suggest that you set System->Configuration->General->Locale to 'English'.

edit2:

**This is a bug in 1.4.x.x, if you want a proper fix - for the love of god update your installation! :)**

**Here's a very nasty patch to core file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Category/Indexer/Product.php**

http://pastebin.com/fWYTsYuX

It is backported from 1.5. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Report! SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't resolve it. This is certainly a pesky one.

Comment: @Michael Watson: Then all I can suggest is you enable query logging and see what query is causing this problem. Checking the call stack from where that query is constructed would be very helpful as well.

Comment: @Michael Watson: you're on the right track but unfortunately it's missing parts of the query. Please enable query logging in the PDO adapter and copy the exact query it is failing on.

Comment: Ah, I thought I had. I've set $_logAllQueries and $_logCallStack to true now, and have edited the original post to show the query that's throwing the exception.

Comment: @MichaelWatson: that's very helpful :) let's see if I can come up with a fix.

Comment: Ah, so the select is giving me catalog_id and product_id. The catalog_category_anc_products_index_idx has these two columns, plus a 'position' column. Still not quite sure what the prob is. Position column should default as null anyway? Again, thanks so much for your help so far Daniel

Comment: @Michael Watson: could you jump into #magento channel on IRC (freenode) real quick? we'll post the solution afterwards but it makes it a lot easier to debug the problem... I am guessing you are on 1.4 or something and have located the issue.

Comment: Sorry, had clients on the phone for far too long. btw, your patch has problems. getCheckSql is an undefined method. Where did that come from? Will be around in irc tomorrow too. Cheers

Comment: As discussed, this is backported from 1.6, not 1.5. Daniel- if you edit that answer above I'll confirm it as correct. Tried and tested, this finally sorted out the silly bug once and for all. Cheers.

Comment: Did Daniel never edit his pastebin diff? I'm getting `Call to undefined method Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::getCheckSql()` as well. Any help? I don't know my way around magento in the slightest.

Comment: @yellottyellott: You might need to copy that method from 1.6 too.

Comment: Had to install magento 1.7 locally and copy the function into
`./lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:class Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql extends Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql implements Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface`

Seems to be working now. Thanks @DanielSloof

Answer (score 1):

Magento, sometimes can be very weird. Try to turn off DEVELOPER_MODE (in .htaccess or index.php) and reindex. It helped for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have not got any products missing a SKU. You can do that from 'manage products' and then clicking on the SKU column to bring the blanks to the top. Delete them or assign SKU's and see if the reindexer works.

Comment: Hey Matthew. Thanks for the response. There were a couple of products without SKUs actually, so I got excited about a solution. But it didn't resolve anything, and the error is still as it was, as above.

Comment: Drat! That normally fixes reindex problems for me but I don't have too many 'bundles'.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for hours I finally found a solution. In fact, It's a very simple solution:

- Backup your database
- Open phpMyAdmin and `truncate` (empty) the table `catalog_product_flat_1`

That's it. After that I was able to index all data and, until now, everything else works perfectly. This worked for me. I hope it works for you too.

Comment: Just as a note, you want to be careful truncating tables unless it's absolutely required. Could have interesting side effects if anything else if referencing or depending on that data.